# Java wsimport on wsdl file produces IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, soap, wsimport

I'm trying to auto-generate for SOAP-Requests using JDKs built-in tool wsimport.
It seems, the files access the internet, because I had to add the argument "-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all". Now, the dependencies seem to be resolved. But the program crashes at returns nothing.
My call:

```
wsimport.exe <Path to .wsdl file> -Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.Plugin:
Provider com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.plugin.at_generated.PluginImpl is specified in
jrt:/jdk.xml.ws/META-INF/services/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.Pluginbut could not be instantiated:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator (in module java.xml.ws)
cannot access class com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.plugin.at_generated.PluginImpl (in module jdk.xml.ws) because module jdk.xml.ws
does not export com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.plugin.at_generated to module java.xml.ws
    at java.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:264)
    at java.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder.access$600(ServiceFinder.java:138)
    at java.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:512)
    at java.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder$CompositeIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:407)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.findServices(WsimportOptions.java:654)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.getAllPlugins(WsimportOptions.java:221)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:402)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:247)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.parseArguments(WsimportTool.java:364)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:187)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:138)
    at jdk.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator (in module java.xml.ws)
cannot access class com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.plugin.at_generated.PluginImpl (in module jdk.xml.ws) because
module jdk.xml.ws does not export com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.plugin.at_generated to module java.xml.ws
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:107)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:553)
    at java.xml.ws@9.0.1/com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:508)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Which Java version? Which framework? Which dependencies?
Show us some code!

Comment: There is no code. Just the .wsdl files. JDK 9.0.1